# Redirect all pages within subdirectory to new page

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

After redoing my webshop, I need to redirect every URL within a certain directoy to a new page.

All URLs beginning ith `example.com/shop/...` should be redirected to the page located at `example.com/products/`.

I'm using [this wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/) for redirections, but I don't know if it can handle it or I need to edit the htaccess file or something.

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/ /products/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

That WordPress plugin should be able to handle this, but otherwise it's just a one-liner in .htaccess (which will also be more efficient):

```
RewriteRule ^shop/ /products/ [R=302,L]
```

The above directive should go after the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives but *before* any other WordPress stuff.

This redirects `/shop/<anything>` to `/products/`.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. Temporary redirects are easier to test since they are not cached by the browser.

Comment: It shouldn't redirect `/shop/<something>` to `/products/<something>, it should redirect `/shop/<something>` to `/products/

Comment: How would you suggest I handle it with the plugin? Redirecting from `/shop/(.*)`doesn't seem to work - what do I need to type?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that plugin.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you explain why you are sugesting a 302 redirect and not 301?

Comment: 302's are easier to test since they are not cached by the browser. Change it to a 301 when you are sure it's working OK - as stated in my answer.

Comment: Just tested it – /shop/random/ just results in a 404 and not redirecting to /products/

Comment: Where have you put this directive? Copy your current .htaccess to your question.

Comment: As stated in my answer, "The above directive should go after the RewriteEngine and RewriteBase directives but before any other WordPress stuff.". You have put the directive at the end where it will never be executed. WordPress uses a _front controller_ (to manage it's pretty URLs) and routes all requests through `index.php`. You need to override this by putting any external redirects before the WordPress rewrites.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your answer closely enough. It works perfect, thank you.